# Lookup value from table based on attribute from separate table in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use data from two models in the same table of a view in  without a Join table.

I want to show a `Game_id` and `Score` from the **Points** table. In a third column, I want to use the `game_id` from **Points** to lookup the value in the `Name` column of the **Game** model matching that same id from **Points**.

In the **ScoreboardController** that will apply to this table, I am trying to first select a set of `Points` and then query the ID:

```
    @points = Point.where(user_id: current_user.id).order(game_id: :desc)
    @find = @points.pluck(:game_id).last
    @game = Game.where(id: @find)
```

Ok, so I am going to show the full list of @points, which includes an id integer for `game_id`. I then try to look up matching game with @game.

Next, I want to show this in a table with the third column picking the `.name` from the row in @game.

```
<tbody>
        <% @points.each do |point| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= point.game_id %></td>
            <td><%= point.virtualmoney %></td>
            <% @game.each do |game| %>
                <td><%= game.name %>
            <% end %>
         <% end %>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

This correctly shows rows of all `game_ids` in the **Points** model with `virtualmoney` earned for that game. I then try to do a second iteration loop with `game.name` -- it loads, but it basically returns the first value for every single row.

So instead of "id: 1 | currency: 5| name: "game 1" ... id: 2 | currency: 3| name: "game 2", it would just be "game 1", "game 1", and so on).

What should I do to return to return a name for each row matching the `game_id` in the first column?

**EDIT: SCHEMA.RB SNIPPET**

```
  create_table "games", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "max_players"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

 create_table "points", force: true do |t|
    t.integer "game_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "points",   default: 0
  end
```

Comment: Can you add your schema.rb?

Comment: @max Good point, just added

Comment: Can you add models so that we can check if the associations are made properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have correct associations, the following will serve your need:

```
<tbody>
    <% @points.each do |point| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= point.game_id %></td>
        <td><%= point.virtualmoney %></td>
        <td><%= point.game.name %></td> 
      </tr>
    <% end %>
</tbody>
```

The thing is, Game `has_many` points, and Point `belongs_to` a Game. So you can get associated game name from your a point object by this - `point.game.name`. Though this violates the law of demeter, but it will do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully understanding what you are trying to do, but hopefully the following points can help. If I understand correctly the following lines are doing nothing:

```
<% @game.each do |game| %>
  <td><%= game.name %>
<% end %>
```

because...

```
@find = @points.pluck(:game_id).last
##Will return only one Game id (e.g. 1)

@game = Game.where(id: @find)
## Will return a ActiveRecord Collection with only one game.
```

In this instance you may well be better off using:

```
@game = Game.find(@find)
```

This is equivalent to calling:

```
@game = Game.where(id: @find).first
```

---

So when iterating through `@game` you just iterating through an ActiveRecord Collection that contains only 1 item.

Including the basic associations you have added would help to understand better.